# object Key in javascript class/dictionary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascipt object which I use as dictionary

```
var obj={
           xxx:'1'
           yyy:'2'
        }
```

However - 
xxx and yyy should be a jQuery **object**.

something like :

```
var obj =
          { 
             $('#div1'):'1' , 
             $('#div2'):'2'
           }
```

is it possible ?

also, How can I **get** the "`value`" for key `$('#div2')` ?

p.s.
I the $.data cant help me here since its also a key value
and i need in the key - object Type also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Object keys can only be strings ( or Symbol), **period.** See [Member Operators - Property Names @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Property_names).

Choose a reasonable string representation, and use that. In this case, I'd say the selector string looks like a decent choice:

```
{ 
    '#div1': '1', 
    '#div2': '2'
}
```

---

> also, How can I **get** the "`value`" for key `$('#div2')` ?

Use one of the member operators, either dot notation

```
var obj = { /* stuff */ };
var value = obj.propertyName;
console.log(value);
```

or bracket notation (more useful for property names not known until runtime):

```
var value = obj['propertyName'];
```

Comment: @not what i wanted to hear but ok :) since im not sure if my element will have an ID. ( not my html...)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to store? I'm not convinced that your data structure is the best representation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WeakMap` which works like a dictionary where the key can be anything. Note that you cannot list all the keys of the map

```js
const aMap = new WeakMap;
const anObject = {};
aMap.set(Number, "It's the Number class")
aMap.set(anObject, "It's an object")

console.log(aMap.get(Number)) // It's the Number class
console.log(aMap.get(anObject)) // It's an object
```